# Should I send goodbye email while I am changing my job in current company

Tags: new-job

I work for a large company, recently I got offer from another section with completely different team and location, I have accepted their offer, my question is : " Should I send a Goodbye email to current team? if yes , what should I say?

Thanks

Comment: What would be the potential downside of sending such an email? On the other hand, what would be the potential *upside* of sending such an email?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should, and say something like:

> Subject: Transferring to Super Widgets Division
>
> I am transferring to the Super Widgets Division in Omaha NE and am really looking forward to my new role as Project Manager for gumbo widgets.   It has been very rewarding working with everyone here in San Francisco, and I will greatly miss everyone.
>
> My email is staying the same, so feel free to stay in touch and I wish all the best to the Super Gizmo Division here in San Francisco.
>
> Thanks
>
> Behrooz Kashani

Be upbeat and supportive of the team you are leaving behind and if you going to be supporting them in any way during the transition mention that too.

It is my experience that there is less stress and anxiety on those left behind if you are upbeat, supportive of the team, and tell them what you are going to be doing.  Even if you were just a contributor on a team and not a manager/team lead, people wonder why you left etc., when you don't say anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually send it in my opinion.
some organisations create recreational alias for this.. I ve seen people trying to contact persons who left their job with so many unicast mail and then after great amount of time and effort , they know your departure from team.,

so saying good bye to your work family when you move forward does not harm in a work environment... Its highly recommenced, people know who should they contact after your departure if you are expert in your module  if you really want to provide pointer for those ( i am talking about the other teams interact with your team)